# Hyperlink in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink

I have few links displayed in JEditorPane ex:

http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE:C

http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:MSFT

I want that I should be able to click them and that it gets displayed in browser

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's a few parts to this:

#### Setup the JEditorPane correctly

The `JEditorPane` needs to have the context type `text/html`, and it needs to be uneditable for links to be clickable:

```
final JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
editor.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
editor.setEditable(false);
```

#### Add the links

You need to add actual `<a>` tags to the editor for them to be rendered as links:

```
editor.setText("<a href=\"http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE:C\">C</a>, <a href=\"http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:MSFT\">MSFT</a>");
```

#### Add the link handler

By default clicking the links won't do anything; you need a [`HyperlinkListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkListener.html) to deal with them:

```
editor.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
        if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
           // Do something with e.getURL() here
        }
    }
});
```

How you launch the browser to handle `e.getURL()` is up to you. One way if you're using Java 6 and a supported platform is to use the [`Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class:

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
}
```

Comment: Feels like this is still a great answer after 10+ years. Is there a better option now?