# Adding action listener to jtable cell text value! not whole cell?

Tags: java, swing

I want to add an `actionListener` to `JTable` cell value which means when the user clicks on cell text, an action going to call. The text of the cell value will show like a hyperlink. which allows the user to click on it.

- Important note: I know how to add an action to the whole cell. My problem is that I want to add it to just a text like a link.

Comment: For clickable links in your cells you can use a JEditorPane for the cell content, and use a HyperLinkListener as explained [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693543/hyperlink-in-jeditorpane)

Answer (score 0):

Try [DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent%28javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int%29) to customize the look and feel of cell item.

Sample code:

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

       JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, obj, isSelected,
                hasFocus, row, column);

       label.setText(some_html_code_that_look_like_hyperlink);
    }
}
```