# how can i add the on hover effect on hyperlink in jeditorpane using swing in java

Tags: java, html, css, swing, hyperlink

Using the [Hyperlink in jEditorPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693543/hyperlink-in-jeditorpane) link, i managed to get the hyperlink in the jEditorPane.

But now i want to add the hover effect to the hyperlink.
I tried to apply the CSS using the

```
MyHTMLEditorKit kit = new MyHTMLEditorKit();
setEditorKitForContentType("text/html", kit);        
addHyperlinkListener(createHyperlinkListener());
StyleSheet css= kit.getStyleSheet();
css.addRule("a { color: red;}");
```

where `MyHTMlEditorKit` extends `HTMLEditorKit`.
Also i tried following CSS, but it didn't worked.

```
a:hover{color:red;}
```

Also, i tried `onmouseover="this.style.color='red'"` attribute in the hyperlink, but even it didn't worked.

So how can i achieve the `onhover` effect for hyperlink in jEditorPane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
styleSheet.addRule("a:hover{color:red;}");
Document doc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
String htmlString = "<a href='stackoverflow.com'>Go to StackOverflow!</a>";
// your JEditorPane
jEditorPane.setDocument(doc);
jEditorPane.setText(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my version, but seems not a good solution. So I wanted to see if anyone had a cleaner approach.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class HoverEffectTest {
  private static final String SO = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
  private final String s = "<a href='%s' color='%s'>%s</a><br>";
  private final String s1 = String.format(s + "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>", SO, "blue", SO);
  private final String s2 = String.format(s + "cccc", SO, "#0000FF", "bbbbbbbbbbb");
  private final JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane(
    "text/html", "<html>" + s1 + s2);
  private JComponent makeUI() {
    editor.setEditable(false);
    //@see: BasicEditorPaneUI#propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    //      if ("foreground".equals(name)) {
    editor.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
    editor.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
      @Override public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
        if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED) {
          setElementColor(e.getSourceElement(), "red");
        } else if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.EXITED) {
          setElementColor(e.getSourceElement(), "blue");
        } else if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
          Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
        //I don't understand why this is necessary...
        //??? call BasicTextUI#modelChanged() ???
        editor.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        editor.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      }
    });
    return new JScrollPane(editor);
  }
  private void setElementColor(Element element, String color) {
    AttributeSet attrs = element.getAttributes();
    Object o = attrs.getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A);
    if (o instanceof MutableAttributeSet) {
      MutableAttributeSet a = (MutableAttributeSet) o;
      a.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.COLOR, color);
    }
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new HoverEffectTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aterai,this helped to add a new feature to my code for the color combinations on mouse hover.