# Change color of Hyperlink in HTMLPanel after click

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I have two JEditorPanes in a JDialog. The first JEditorPane displays an HTML document that contains a list of links that can be clicked. The second one displays the URL when the user clicks on a link.

I want to change the color of the clicked link to black, so the user easily recognizes what link he clicked last.

I used this code

```
  @Override
  public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
    if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
      if (e.getSource() instanceof JEditorPane) {
        JEditorPane editor = ((JEditorPane) e.getSource());
        editor.requestFocusInWindow();
        editor.setSelectionStart(e.getSourceElement().getStartOffset());
        editor.setSelectionEnd(e.getSourceElement().getEndOffset());
        editor.setSelectedTextColor(Color.black);
        editor.setSelectionColor(Color.white);

        loadUrl(e.getUrl);
      }
    }
  }
```

Sadly this **only works when** the **JEditorPane has** the **focus**. Since I also have a JTextField in my JDialog, that I want to never lose focus, my current solution no longer works.

I tried the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820178/how-can-i-add-the-on-hover-effect-on-hyperlink-in-jeditorpane-using-swing-in-jav), but they did not work in my case.

**Edit:** Using CSS did not work unfortunately. This the HTML Code that is displayed in my JEditorPane

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">a:hover{color:red;}</style>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body><ul><li><a href="file:/pathToFile.html">Path to File</a></li></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

but still I don't get the hover effect.

**Edit 2:** posted my own solution for the problem as answer. Still I'd love to know why CSS didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *CSS* ability 
Just write this code

HTML:

```
<a href="#" > something </a>
```

CSS:

```
    /* unvisited link */

a:link {

    color: red;

}

​

/* visited link */

a: visited {

    color: green;

}

​

/* mouse over link */

a:hover {

    color: pink;

}

​

/* selected link */

a:active {

    color: blue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
private final DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainterLightGray 
    = new DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

@Override
public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
  if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
    myJEditorPane.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
    myJEditorPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(
      e.getSourceElement().getStartOffset(),
      e.getSourceElement().getEndOffset(), highlightPainterLightGray);
  }
}
```

This doesn't change the color of the font like I initially wanted, but changes the background color instead. This also gives the user a good feeling for what link he clicked last and that was my goal.